# Python group similar files names

Tags: python-2.7, list, compare, delta

I have a directory that contains 2000 .txt files, with various sizes.  Some of them have very similar names, such as:

```
trend_micro.txt
trendmicro.txt
```

and

```
microsoft-windows.txt
microsoft.txt
```

I have all the filenames in a list.  How would I go about grouping these similar filenames together?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how you define "similar" and "dissimilar". Here I assume two filenames are similar if they become the same after throwing away "-" and "_".The following code should do the work

```
def reduce_key(fn):
    # you can change this according to your definition of "similar"
    return fn.replace("-","").replace("_","")

from collections import defaultdict
# this holds the grouped filenames
group_dict = defaultdict(list)
for fn in your_list:
    key = reduce_key(fn)
    group_dict[key].append(fn)

print(group_dict)
```